# Ruby on Rails - Decrease weight of images and re-process them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, paperclip

I have a site in Ruby On Rails and to attachments uploads I use Paperclip. My server is running out of space and much of what it is occupying are the images that were sent through Paperclip.

In my Models I already set the size of attachment, like:

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: { original: '1920x', thumb: '100x100# }
```

Than I run and `MyModel.all.each{|p| p.image.reprocess!}` that really reprocess the attachments, but the size of some files continue to heavy (over 2mb). How can I decrease weight of images and re-process them directly in server?

Thanks.